# Android studio do not show devices for flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am new to Flutter and android studio, I followed the instructions of flutter.io ,  I created a blank app, and while I try to run I am unable to see the device lists. but it is available in device manager 
Please see the screenshot.[image]

Comment: in your image, under actions, click the play button, the emulator will start and will then show in available devices. otherwise, it will not.

Comment: Hope it helps https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2084

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->Troubleshoot Device Connections.

1. Connect your device over USB
     If your device name does not show here then your USB or device has a problem.
2. You have to enable USB Debugging on your device.
3. Restart ADB Server.

I hope this addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've not run your device....
Under Actions Click the Run button......
The emulator will start and your problem solved..

Comment: emulator already started, but it is not loading the simple one page app... will it take time ?